# Odd object movement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a delightful rectangle named ship, which I control with the right and left arrow keys. When I initially press a key ship moves in the opposite direction it should for the first movement, then goes back the right way. What would be an elegant solution to this particular conundrum?

```
public double p = 0;

    private void Window_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            ship.Margin = new Thickness(p, 259, 0, 12);
            p = p + 10;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            ship.Margin = new Thickness(p, 259, 0, 12);
            p = p - 10;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the value of `p` *after* you set the margin. That means you're effectively always one key-press behind. I would expect you to want to set it *before* you make the change. (I'm not sure that setting the margin is *really* the ideal way of moving something around, mind you...)

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure if it's 'standard', but more generally `Canvas.SetLeft` etc. see more use.

Comment: I assume he got that idea from the WPF designer in Visual Studio. It also does this.

Comment: Well, could any of you recommend a better way of doing this?

Comment: Never mind, by playing around with something else I found a good method that I can apply to this.

Answer (score 0):

Consier removing field for current left margin. You can get current ship margin before you change it. Also split handling user input and ship movement operations:

```
// Handle user input
private void Window_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.Key)
    {
        case (Key.Right): 
              MoveShip(Direction.Right); return;
        case (Key.Left): 
              MoveShip(Direction.Left); return;
        default:
            return;
    }
}        

// Here you implement ship movement (Margin, Canvas.SetLeft, etc)
private void MoveShip(Direction direction)
{
    var margin = ship.Margin; // or create copy here
    const int distance = 10;

    switch(direction)
    {
       case(Direction.Left):
            margin.Left -= distance;
            break;
       case(Direction.Right):
            margin.Left += distance;
            break;
       default:
            return;
    }

    ship.Margin = margin;
}

private enum Direction
{
    Left,
    Right
}
```